# Adding two values inputted by a user

Tags: java

What should i do to make the two values which were inputted by the user to be added?

```
import java.io.*;

public class InputOutput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String base="";
        String height="";

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            System.out.print("Input base value = ");
            base = input.readLine();
            System.out.print("Input height value = ");
            height = input.readLine();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Error");
        }

        System.out.println("The base is "+base+height);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `System.out.println("The base is "+base+height);
`?

Comment: @Oswald OP wants `"The base is "+base+height` (when `base=2` and `height=3`) to be `The base is 5`. Here it becomes `The base is 23`

Comment: Was one of the answers below acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

First, convert both input strings into numbers, for example with [`Integer.parseInt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

When you "add" two strings (or a string and a number), the result is the concatenation of these strings. The result of adding numbers is their sum, as you would expect, so your final line should look like:

```
System.out.println("The base is " + (baseNumber+heightNumber));
```

Comment: shouldn't converting string to int be better?

Comment: @js david Yes, `parseInt` (which returns an `int`, compared to `valueOf`, which returns an `Integer`) is indeed the better choice, though due to automatic unboxing, both work. What I wanted to stress is that an `int` (or `Integer`) is not always the best choice, especially if you expect large or fractional inputs.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you are treating `base` and `height` as strings.

So you have:

```
base + height = "2" + "3" = "23"
```

That is `+` is string concatenation.

You need to use `Integer.parseInt` to convert them to `int`s and then add them:

```
int ibase = Integer.parseInt(base);
int iheight = Integer.parseInt(height);
int sum = ibase + iheight;
System.out.println("The base is " + sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = Integer.parseInt(base)+ Integer.parseInt(height);
System.out.println("The base is "+ sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why does everyone want to parse it? Just change the type of `base` and `height` to `int` and use:

```
input.nextInt()
```